# How to add Dictionary to Plist in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, plist

i have a dictionary of type as below

```
var favoriteGooglelocations = [Int:GoogleItems]()
```

where GoogleItems is class.

```
class GoogleItems: NSObject {

    var name:String?
    var address:String?
    var distance : String?
    var googleLocation: CLLocation?
    var isStar : Bool?

}
```

And i am writing to the dictionary as :

```
var newLocation = GoogleItems()
newLocation.name = locations[sender.tag].name
newLocation.address = locations[sender.tag].address
newLocation.distance = locations[sender.tag].distance
favoriteGooglelocations[sender.tag] = newLocation
```

When i try to write this dictionary it gives me compile time error   `favoriteGooglelocations.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)`

> Error : >  [Int : GoogleItems] does not have a member named
>   writeToFile

**UPDATED**:
The path i am writing is

```
 let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)

 let documentDirectory = paths[0] as! String

 path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Favorites.plist")
```

**How can i add Dictionary to PList,Is there other way to do this?**

Comment: Hi,I update the code I test,you may refer to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert Dictionary to `NSDictionary` so that you can use `writeToFile`

Try to cast with this

```
let succeed = (favoriteGooglelocations as NSDictionary).writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

If succeed is false,check your GoogleItems class,it should conforms to `NSCoding`

**Update**,this is the code I test,you may refer to it

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
```

Set you `GoogleItems` conforms to NSCoding

```
class GoogleItems: NSObject,NSCoding {
override init() {}
var name:String?
var address:String?
var distance : String?
var googleLocation: CLLocation?
var isStar : Bool?
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as? String
    self.address = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("address") as? String
    self.distance = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("distance") as? String
    self.googleLocation = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("googleLocation") as? CLLocation
    self.isStar = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("isStar") as? Bool
}
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    if name != nil{  aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")}
    if address != nil{ aCoder.encodeObject(address, forKey: "address")}
    if distance != nil { aCoder.encodeObject(distance, forKey: "distance")}
    if googleLocation != nil { aCoder.encodeObject(googleLocation, forKey: "googleLocation")}
    if isStar != nil {aCoder.encodeBool(isStar!, forKey: "isStar")}
}
}
```

Then write to file

```
    var favoriteGooglelocations = [Int:GoogleItems]()
    var item = GoogleItems()
    item.isStar = true
    item.name = "name"
    item.address = "address"
    item.googleLocation = nil
    item.distance = "23"
    favoriteGooglelocations[1] = item
    let dic = favoriteGooglelocations as NSDictionary
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectory = paths[0] as! String
    let  path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Favorites.plist")
    let succeed = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(dic, toFile: path)
    println(succeed)
```

Read from file

```
     let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)

    let documentDirectory = paths[0] as! String

    let  path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Favorites.plist")
    let dic = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path) as? [Int:GoogleItems]
    if(dic != nil){
        for (key,value) in dic!{
            let item = value
            println(item.name)
            println(item.address)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you post your path?Maybe your path is not writeable

Comment: here it is /Users/bikram/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3333ED17-BFFB-44B8-BACA-967E5D9A3E38/data/Containers/Data/Application/AC822088-C106-4588-9C6E-C6360E0257F3/Documents/Favorites.plist

Comment: all thing is good...if is just write a string it does well...and i can see the changes in the plist of document directory

Comment: See my updates,you should let your` GoogleItems` conforms to `NSCoding`

Comment: No need to cast to NSDictionary if GoogleItems conforms to NSCoding

Comment: if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(favoriteGooglelocations, toFile: path) {
    if let loadedDic = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path) as? [Int:GoogleItems] {
        println(loadedDic[1]!)
    }
}

Comment: What do you mean by ` why can i see the data`? Do you mean `Where`?

Comment: sorry i am able to see the data in PList in document directory..but not able to parse it :( http://s27.postimg.org/j2qkmr3s3/Screen_Shot_2015_06_05_at_12_56_14_PM.png

Comment: Data is archived,that is what it should be.

Comment: but i have many data ..how do i parse those all...means loop through all the data

Comment: You use `unarchiveObjectWithFile`,it will auto return a dictionary. You do need to parse the data youself

Comment: yeah..but how do i show all the items saved in dic ? not a single item as  let item = dic?.objectForKey(NSNumber(int: 1)) as? GoogleItems

Comment: for (key, value) in dic {
            println("Property: \"\(key as String)\"")
        } its not working?

Comment: @Leo.. while i print as println(item.isStar) it gives me nil..is that due to NSCoding..coz i can see the value in plist

Answer (score 1):

update: **Xcode 7.2 • Swift 2.1.1**

You can use  NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject() as follow:

```
let dictionary:[String:String] = ["key1" : "value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"]

let documentDirectoryURL =  NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
let fileURL = documentDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("dictionary.plist")
if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(dictionary, toFile: fileURL.path!) {
    print(true)
}

if let loadedDic = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(fileURL.path!) as? [String:String] {
    print(loadedDic)   // "["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"]\n"
}
```

If GoogleItems conforms to NSCoding

```
if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(favoriteGooglelocations, toFile: fileURL.path!) {
    if let loadedDic = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(fileURL.path!) as? [Int:GoogleItems] {
        println(loadedDic)
    }
}
```

Comment: let dictionaryData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(favoriteGooglelocations)
            
            if dictionaryData.writeToURL(path, atomically: true) {
                println(true)
            }.....while i try this it gives me compile time error in if statement

Comment: when i tried as    let dictionaryData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(favoriteGooglelocations)
            let result = dictionaryData.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)...it gives me error as nrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa4d09aee10'   please see my updated question

Comment: You need to conform your class to NSCoding